# Microsoft Graph API: How to set the culture of an Excel Pdf conversion

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I use Microsoft Graph to convert Excel files to Pdfs. In general, this is working fine, but I find no way to pass the culture. For example, dates are always printed using the en-us formatting.

With no effect I have tried to set the threading culture.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<Stream> ConvertToPdfAsync(string extension, Stream stream)
{
    var fileName = $"/temp/ConvertToPdf/{Guid.NewGuid()}.{extension}";

    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(_authProvider);

    await graphClient.Users[_sender]
        .Drive
        .Root
        .ItemWithPath(fileName)
        .Content
        .Request()
        .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);

    var outStream = await graphClient.Users[_sender]
        .Drive
        .Root
        .ItemWithPath(fileName)
        .Content
        .Request(new List<Option>() { new QueryOption("format", "pdf") })
        .GetAsync();

    await graphClient.Users[_sender]
        .Drive
        .Root
        .ItemWithPath(fileName)
        .Request()
        .DeleteAsync();

    return outStream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, at this point you don't have option to explicitly specify culture with Graph API for conversion.

You may consider filing **[Microsoft Graph feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform)**, so that it can be considered to be implemented.